# SQL Server correlated queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, correlated-subquery

I currently have some SQL code which looks like this.

```
SELECT
    WORKORDER_BASE_ID As 'Work Order',
    SCHED_START_DATE AS 'Scheduled Start',
    SETUP_HRS AS 'Approx Setup Hrs',
    RUN_HRS AS 'Approx Run Hrs',
    (
        SELECT 
            PART_ID as "Components" 
        FROM 
            REQUIREMENT 
        WHERE 
            REQUIREMENT.WORKORDER_BASE_ID = OPERATION.WORKORDER_BASE_ID
            AND REQUIREMENT.WORKORDER_SUB_ID = OPERATION.WORKORDER_SUB_ID
            AND PART_ID LIKE '%PSU%'
    )   AS PSU
FROM 
    OPERATION
WHERE 
    OPERATION.STATUS = 'R' 
    AND RESOURCE_ID LIKE '%{Root Container.equipmentName}%'
```

I am receiving errors because the sub-query generates more than one field. What I need is a way to specify a condition to the sub-query to only display data pertaining to a the specific work order in that row, specifically the work order number. I'm guessing this is some sort of loop function.

Any suggestions?

BTW, the bottom line is correct. The platform I use interprets values in braces as local variables.

Comment: Can you quote the exact error please?

Comment: You already have this:
`REQUIREMENT.WORKORDER_BASE_ID = OPERATION.WORKORDER_BASE_ID
 AND REQUIREMENT.WORKORDER_SUB_ID = OPERATION.WORKORDER_SUB_ID`
What else does it take to get one record?

Comment: A Sub-Query in select MUST return a scalar value. Use TOP 1 in your select and it should fix the issue.

Comment: You have multiple `REQUIREMENT.PART_ID`'s for each OPERATION row.  Which one do you want?  Without any further info, one *fix* would be to return `MAX(PART_ID)` instead of `PART_ID`.  Whether this does what you want only you can say.

Comment: , database=FV_VM)@5000ms
On: FV_Recipe_Page.Root Container.Table.data
 caused by GatewayException: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
 caused by SQLServerException: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Ignition v7.6.6 (b2014040112)
Java: Oracle Corporation 1.7.0_45

Comment: The conditions I have under where currently appear to only link the columns from two tables together. There are still a half dozen or so entries generated. The only way I can get the code to work is if I equate the WORKORDER_BASE_ID to an actual numerical ID.

Comment: What you're saying is that if you remove your sub query, and add `WORKORDER_SUB_ID` to the main query, you'll get multiple rows from `OPERATION` for a single `WORKORDER_BASE_ID` AND `WORKORDER_SUB_ID`.  Now, how can it decide which records from `REQUIREMENT` to assign to each?

Comment: I would not use a correlated subquery like this. It is a performance killer and it should not be a technique anyone who is not a dba should ever consider using.  It is a SQL antipattern.

Comment: @HLGEM I wouldn't say that.  In the vast majority of cases, correlated subqueries are simple queries.  They almost always will get optimized into semi-joins by the query optimizer.  Yes, it's better to do an explicit join in general, but when you're trying to pull, say, just the first phone number for a person, a `TOP 1 ... ORDER BY Priority` will usually work great and actually end up easier to read than the groupwise maximum hoops you'd normally have to jump through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Sub-Query in select MUST return a scalar value. Use TOP 1 in your select and it should fix the issue. Or Alternately you can do the following ....

```
SELECT OPERATION.WORKORDER_BASE_ID   AS [Work Order]
      ,OPERATION.SCHED_START_DATE    AS [Scheduled Start]
      ,OPERATION.SETUP_HRS           AS [Approx Setup Hrs]
      ,OPERATION.RUN_HRS             AS [Approx Run Hrs]
      ,REQUIREMENT.PART_ID           AS [Components] 
FROM  OPERATION
INNER JOIN REQUIREMENT ON REQUIREMENT.WORKORDER_BASE_ID = OPERATION.WORKORDER_BASE_ID
                      AND REQUIREMENT.WORKORDER_SUB_ID = OPERATION.WORKORDER_SUB_ID
WHERE OPERATION.[STATUS] ='R' 
  AND OPERATION.RESOURCE_ID LIKE '%{Root Container.equipmentName}%'
  AND REQUIREMENT.PART_ID LIKE '%PSU%'
```

Comment: The join qwquery is fine but top 1 is a terrible idea as you do not know which o f those multiple records ahsa the value you want.

Comment: @HLGEM true and also it gets executed for each row returned by the outer query and absolute disaster performance wise, thats why I have suggested this INNER JOIN solution.

Comment: Hey, M. Ali, thanks I tried your code, and I get a different message. `, database=FV_VM)@5000ms
On: FV_Recipe_Page.Root Container.Table.data
 caused by GatewayException: Ambiguous column name 'WORKORDER_BASE_ID'.
 caused by SQLServerException: Ambiguous column name 'WORKORDER_BASE_ID'.` I've seen this before and don't understand why this would happen with two columns I am trying to join.

Comment: Use Two-part names in your Select list , `WORKORDER_BASE_ID` column exists in both tables you need to use the tablename.columnName in your select to tell sql server from which table to select this column. I have updated the answer have a look.